# Solutions from StackOverflow to prevent XSS in JSP pages don't work

Tags: xss, jsp

I have a JSP page where the HTML title is pulled from a GET parameter `title`:

```
<title>${title}</title>
```

Obviously, this allows for XSS attacks. If I follow the answer given on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application) and try the solutions

```
<title><c:out value="${title}"/></title>
<title>${fn:escapeXml(title)}</title>
```

(while importing the respective taglibs), it doesn't work.  The test attack

```
https://example.com/page.jsp?title=“/><script>alert(1)</script>
```

still works.  What am I doing wrong with these solutions?